# Movie where guy is solicited by young teen prostitute and he ends up raising her?

Tags: identify-this-movie

Movie where guy is solicited by young teen prostitute and he ends up raising her?

He first sees her with another potential client; she either already has or gets a black eye and tries to have sex with him.  He gives her a sandwich.  Then he runs into her later and ends up taking her to his apartment to look after her.  She ends up going to school, etc.

If I remember correctly, it's a recent movie with the male lead being mid 20s.

Comment: Welcome to the Raileys?

Comment: @Larme looks like a match, why not you add it as an answer?

Comment: I didn't see the movie, just the trailer a long time ago. So I don't know if it matches all your memories of this movie.

Comment: @Larme - You should add it as an answer, and let the OP judge later if it is correct or not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, I figured it out.  The movie is "Detachment" with Adrien Brody.
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1683526/

The other answer made me realize I was going to need more details to differentiate the movies, and when I got to thinking about them, I remembered!

*Detachment*'s two story arcs sort of separated into two separate movies for me.  Anyway, I enjoyed the movie more than most, so I intend to watch it again.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 7):

Seems to be the plot of Welcome to the Riley's with *James Gandolfini* as the man and *Kristen Stewart* as the prostitue/stripper.
[Here's the IMDB page](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1183923/)

The Plot (from [WikiPedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welcome_to_the_Rileys)):

> Ever since the death of their daughter Emily, Doug (James Gandolfini)
> and Lois Riley (Melissa Leo) have been drifting apart. As Lois
> wrestles with a suffocating sense of guilt over her daughter's death,
> Doug copes by entering into an affair with Vivian, a local waitress.
> Lately, Lois hasn't even been able to muster the courage to venture
> outside, summoning hairdressers to her home in order to maintain
> appearances and communicating with few people other than her sister
> Harriet and the local pastor. When Vivian dies and Doug finds himself
> in a New Orleans strip club during a business trip, he realizes he's
> come to a dangerous crossroads in life.
>
> Turning down an offer for a
> private dance by 16-year-old stripper Mallory (Kristen Stewart), Doug
> instead accompanies the girl home and makes a most unusual
> proposition: If Mallory will allow him to stay in her run-down house
> long enough to straighten himself out, he will pay her $100 a day for
> her trouble. For Mallory, who isn't used to getting money for nothing,
> it seems like a great deal. She accepts, and Doug phones Lois to tell
> her he won't be coming home. As time passes, Doug and Mallory settle
> into an unconventional kind of domesticity.
>
> Meanwhile, back home, Lois
> realizes that she'll have to act fast in order to save her marriage,
> even if that means venturing well outside her comfort zone for the
> first time in nearly a decade. Most days she can't even make it to the
> mailbox, but after a couple of attempts, Lois manages to start up her
> car and get on the freeway heading south. When Lois arrives in
> Louisiana and discovers that her husband is living with a
> foul-mouthed, underage stripper, she is at first horrified. Like Doug
> before her, however, Lois quickly warms to Mallory due in part to her
> striking similarities to Emily. Before long, Lois, too, has moved in,
> and the three form an unconventional family. But when Lois attempts to
> steer Mallory from the path of self-destruction, the young girl
> bristles. Mallory is arrested after an altercation with a client, and
> Doug and Lois rush to be by her side, but shortly after they bail her
> out, she runs away. Doug and Lois realize they cannot use Mallory as a
> substitute for their daughter and return to Indianapolis. Shortly
> after returning and settling back at home, Doug receives a phone call
> from Mallory in Houston. She announces her plans about moving to Las
> Vegas, just before boarding the bus. Doug clarifies to her that she
> will always be supported by his family, if any needs should come. Doug
> and Lois finally begin to re-engage with the world.